# Wagtail: How do I use RichTextField for string representation of a model?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am currently working on this snippet

```
@register_snippet
class Foo(models.Model):
    body = RichTextField()
```

Somehow I decided that I need to define `__str__` so that I can distinguish between multiple snippets. I believe that using `body` contents as the string representation might be a good idea. Although, body can grow incredibly large, so the first 20 characters should do.

Thinking this task is a piece of cake, I wrote this code:

```
@register_snippet
class Foo(models.Model):
    body = RichTextField() 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[:20]
```

... which resulted in ugly representations such as `<p>Quequeueueueue?</` and `<p>FOO<br/></p>`.

I checked the database and found out that the markup is stored in the database, which seemed pretty obvious. Although, I'm still wondering.

What is the way to remove HTML markup without using CPU-heavy HTML parsers and parsing the whole `body`?

I believe regular expressions can remove *some* tags, but how do I handle situations like `</a`, `</blockqu`, `<`, `</`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in way to safely escape html. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#removetags)-

**Deprecated since version 1.8**:
`removetags` cannot guarantee HTML safe output and has been deprecated due to security concerns. Consider using bleach instead.

[Bleach](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is an html sanitizing library from Mozilla. It may make the most sense to create a method on your snippet class that returns a bleached string, removing all tags.

In addition, you can use the [built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) `truncatewords`, `truncatechars`, etc to limit how many characters/words are shown upon template rendering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Although, wouldn't it be kind of "wrong" to require a whole library just to build a __str__ method for a single model?

Comment: I think the answer on that relies on whether or not external users will be able to submit data. :) If extreme safety isn't needed, then regex should be able to sort it out!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment by @Ian Price, if you can trust the content you're working on, a regex works fine. For example:

```
import re

...

def __str__(self):
    remove_tags = re.compile('<.*?>')
    return re.sub(remove_tags, '', self.body)
```